# Is it okay that this answer was deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

[This](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/82644/44276) answer was deleted. You'll only be able to see it if you have requisite privileges.

[This](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/82644/revisions) is the revision history. The answer seems alright.

One problem is the irrelevant link, which might be why it was deleted but that could have been just edited out. It is also a strict subset of the other answer, but that's not the reason I have seen answers getting deleted for.

I don't understand what's going on. Is this some policy that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Yes, it contains a spam link.

Comment: @wrod, is that all? That link could have been edited out simply, why delete the entire answer

Comment: That's generally not the policy regarding spam. Even if an answer *looks* legit, if it's actually spam, it gets deleted.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the answer was deleted because it was spam. A common theme with spam on the SE network is that spam links will be embedded within innocent-looking answers which are actually plagiarised, either from other websites, generative AI, or other answers.

In this case, it was the last option - the answer is a rewrite of the first paragraph of the [other answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/82635/) to that question, with each sentence put into slightly different words.

Please flag such posts as spam  rather than editing out the spam link, as it helps train the SE spam filter, and prevents spam from remaining public-facing within the edit history.

Answer (score 3):

The last thing we need to be doing is incentivizing spammers from posting here by giving their crap any longer of a lifetime than is strictly necessary to find and delete it.

Any serious poster would know not to put their post at risk with spam, so the bar is pretty low in assuming that spam answers are as useful as sunscreen during polar winters.

And, if it's a new user, is that the kind of user this site wants?  Post can always be undeleted if there was a mistake.